# Given a function $f:X\to X$ such that $f\circ f = \operatorname{Id}_X$. Prove that if $f(x)≠x$ for all $x\in X$, then $|X|$ is even.

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

My thinking so far is considering proving the contrapositive statement: $|X|$ is odd $\implies \exists x \in X $ such that $f(x)=x$, but I can't think of any method of doing this at all. How am I supposed to link the parity of the cardinality to a statement about an identity map???

I tried imposing an ordering on $X$ to make things more explicit, i.e. equivalently consider $f:X_n \to X_n$ where $X_n=\{1,2,...,n\}$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$. But what does having $n$ = odd show?

Comment: If the map does not fix any element, then the map just swaps pairs (as $f\circ f(x)=x$). Hence, $\vert X \vert$ must be even.

Comment: You might want to add the condition that $X$ is a finite set.

Comment: If |X| is odd, can't I still swap elements in pairs?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $f(x)=x$ for some $x\in X$. What is $f(f(x))$?

Now what if $f(x)\ne x$?

Answer (score 1):

Note that since $f$ is an involution, it always splits the initial space in pairs of points and fixed points. More precisely, we will prove the classical combinatorial result that
$$\# X \equiv_2 \# F_f $$
(equivalence modulo $2$), where $F_f$ is the set of fixed points of $f.$ Let us pick $x \in X.$ If it is a fixed point, it defines a one-cycle $(x).$ If not, $f(x) = y \neq x,$ but $f(y) = x,$ so it defines a two-cycle $(x, y).$ Note that all these cycles are disjoint and obviously the set of points in two-cycles is even. Thus we have obtained the decomposition
$$X = C_2 \sqcup F_f = \{x, y \in X : f(x) = y \neq x \text{ and } f(y) = x\} \sqcup \{z \in X: f(z) = z\}.$$
The result follows. In particular in your case, you have no fixed points, so $X$ has even cardinality. I hope this helps. :)

Answer (score 0):

Suppose the statement is false. Let $f : X \rightarrow X$ be a counterexample such that the cardinality of $X$ is smallest. $|X|$ is odd so $X$ is not empty.  Also, $|X|$ cannot be 1, as then $f(x) \neq x$ is impossible.

Now, let $x \in X$ be arbitrary, and $y = f(x)$. By assumption, $y \neq f(x)$, and $f(y) = x$. Furthermore, by $f \circ f = id$, $f$ is a bijection.

Thus, if $z \notin \{x, y\}$ then $f(z) \notin \{x, y\}$ either. Thus, $f$ restricted to $X - \{x, y\}$ is a smaller counterexample.

Comment: Is the notation $X-\{x,y\}$ supposed to mean $X\setminus \{x,y\}$?

Comment: @HollandDavis yes